# Redirect all /?p=xxx to /archives/xxx in htaccess (permanently)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am getting lots of 404 errors for URLs that end in /?p=xxx. The "xxx" always corresponds to a real page, namely, /archives/xxx. So I'd like to just use a rule in my htaccess file to permanently redirect all of these otherwise 404 errors to their correct page.

Example:

```
/?p=12017        # produces a 404 error
/archives/12017  # is the correct page
```

I ask because the last time I tried to use regex in my htaccess file on my own, I broke the site. Surely you all are better at regex than I am. :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/\?p=(.*)$ \/archives\/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(Credit to James for helping me arrive at this answer).